# Render an HTMLImageElement dom node in Preact

Tags: javascript, image, dom, jsx, preact

(Attention: I am asking about **Preact**, not **React** for which there are solutions using Reacts `DomElement` wrapper component).

I have an `HTMLImageElement`, which is created using `var img = document.createElement('img')`. How can I render this manually created DOM Element using Preact?

The following JSX snippet works, but is very slow for larger images on mobile devices:

```
<img src={img.src} />
```

I assume it is so slow because the image instance is copied in-memory instead of using the existing DOM node and image buffer.

Any better (faster) solutions?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the [`react-dom-element-wrapper`](https://github.com/antialias/react-dom-element-wrapper/blob/master/index.js) component is pretty easy to port to `preact`, the main difference being that in `preact`, `props.children` will always be an `Array`.

See if this component can render your image:

```
// Based on https://github.com/antialias/react-dom-element-wrapper/blob/master/index.js
class DomWrapper extends Component {
    update = () => {
        let fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
        this.props.children.forEach((child) => fragment.appendChild(child))
        this.el.innerHTML = '';
        this.el.appendChild(fragment);
    }

    componentDidMount() { this.update(); }

    componentDidUpdate() { this.update(); }

    render() {
        return <div ref={(el) => this.el = el} />
    }
}
```

Example Usage: http://jsfiddle.net/epc3skk3/6/

Answer (score 0):

maybe it might work. do this quick and simple rendering of html elements https://www.npmjs.com/package/preact-append-child